# Can't compile in Eclipse - unhandled event loop exception

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I can't compile my gwt application in Eclipse. Works in Maven outside
Eclipse though. I'm getting an error related to IPixelConverter (see
below for full stacktrace). The version of Eclipse is 3.5.1
(SpringSource Tool Suite2.3.0) and version 2.1.0 of GWT Plugin
installed from the 3.5 update site.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

**

> eclipse.buildId=2.3.0.200912171331-RELEASE java.version=1.6.0_22
>   java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=sv_SE Framework arguments:  -product
>   com.springsource.sts.ide Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32
>   -arch x86_64 -product com.springsource.sts.ide

**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/
ui/IPixelConverter
        at
com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.ui.GWTCompileDialog.createAdvancedOptions(GWTCompileDialog.java:
337)
        at
com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.ui.GWTCompileDialog.createDialogArea(GWTCompileDialog.java:
250)
        at
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:
147)
        at
com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.ui.GWTCompileDialog.createContents(GWTCompileDialog.java:
215)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
        at
com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.actions.GWTCompileToolbarAction.run(GWTCompileToolbarAction.java:
64)
        at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:
251)
        at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:
229)
        at
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:
584)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access
$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem
$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:
3880)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:
2405)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
        at
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:
332)
        at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:
493)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:
149)
        at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:
113)
        at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:
194)
        at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:
110)
        at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:
79)
        at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:
368)
        at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:
179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:
39)
        at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared.ui.IPixelConverter
        at
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:
494)
        at
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:
410)
        at
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:
398)
        at
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:
105)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem above.

Error An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/ui/IPixelConverter.

You need to Install / reinstall
"Jetty-9 Bundles Composite Repository" - http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x
Checklist only: Jetty - Bundles: all the jetty bundles.